# How Can I Get RegEx Groups From Python re Without Matching?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

If I compile a regex such as:

```
pat = re.compile("/resource/([a-z]*)/")
```

Is it possible to get matching components of this pattern (e.g., "/resource/", "([a-z]*)", "/") or some equivalent without executing *match*, *search*, or some other regex call? I want to know how the pattern "breaks out".

For example, the object's *groups* attribute tells me there is 1 group. But not much more information.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: It looks like you want to do something similar to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls . If you're not using Django, what are you using? There might be a similar feature in your framework. Otherwise maybe look at the source of one of the frameworks that does this or try to find a library.

Comment: Suppose this was a generic URL "/r/([a-z]*)/", it would match "/r/foo/", "/r/bar/", etc. An internal component knows nothing about URL but it knows _fetch(ID1)_, _fetch(ID2)_.

I would like to create a function that can map a generic URL to the internal  representation. For example:

`shimfunc("/r/([a-z]*)/", [ ("foo", ID1), ("bar", ID2)])` ==> URL pattern is "/r/", <group>, "/" ==> so generate/return { "/r/foo/": ID1, "/r/bar/": ID2 } to be used later.

Answer (score 2):

Use [regex101's](https://regex101.com) debugger feature. You can see how your regex failed or succeeded step-by-step.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Wow I have been using this tool forever and didn''t know this existed. Super useful!